# Generation of IP list not working (Python)

Tags: python

I need to generate a list of 250 IP addresses.

Code:

```
import random

tarlist = 'targets.txt'
seed = input("Enter First Octet (example'192' '172' '10'):   ")

def make_list():

    octet2 = (random.randrange(255))
    octet3 = (random.randrange(255))
    octet4 = (random.randrange(255))
    for x in range(250):
        with open(tarlist, 'a'):

            ipadd = (seed, '.' + str(octet2), '.' + str(octet3), '.' + str(octet4).lstrip(' '))
        with open(tarlist, 'w') as tl:
            tl.writelines(ipadd)

make_list()
print("START")
```

I've tried `for` loops and used the `range` function. It caused the variables to be be declared improperly.

Comment: Your commas are wrong and are causing the trouble.  `ipadd = f"{seed}.{octet2}.{octet3}.{octet4}"` is all you need.  You should open the file before you start the loop, and just write the string one at a time.  Or, return a list (like the function name says), and have the caller write it to file.  Also, right now you are writing 250 identical IP addresses.  Did you intend for `x` to be the fourth octet?

Comment: Did you notice that your output file only ever contains one line?

Answer (score 0):

You should open the output file once (mode 'w') then loop within the context manager. Something like this:

```
from random import randrange

tarlist = 'targets.txt'
seed = input("Enter First Octet (example'192' '172' '10'):   ")

def make_list():
    with open(tarlist, 'w') as tl:
        for _ in range(250):
            octet2 = randrange(255)
            octet3 = randrange(255)
            octet4 = randrange(255)
            print(f'{seed}.{octet2}.{octet3}.{octet4}', file=tl)

make_list()
```